# VOB file datestamp

Tags: video

Can anyone tell me the structure of a VOB file or how to get the datetime stamp for each frame?

Comment: Not sure if this will help, but is some information on the VOB file structure,  http://www.mpucoder.com/DVD/vobov.html

Comment: certainly a good start. I'll let you know how I go. Thanks